# Mysql: how to properly store information from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm working on a POST register system. Simply every single post request that is sent to the site must be recorded as well as everything the user had posted ( in other words the $_POST array ).

I see 2 ways of doing this:

The right way - having a separate table `registerPostInfo` for post information where every single element of the array will be inserted as a new record.

The wrong way - creating an additional column to my `registerPost` table which would hold the `json_encode()`'d post array.

I'm asking for advice because eventhough it may be considered 'WRONG' I honestly think I'll be better off with the second solution, because this table gets flooded like crazy. I have made 2000 records all by myself in a one month testing period on a local server, if I were to proceed with the first solution, say there are an average of 5 elements in the post array, this means there were going to be 10000 records in the `registerPostInfo` table. Imagine that with thousands of people.. I'll be happy for any useful information about my issue and possibly a third way I haven't thought of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your schema look like? Perhaps there are flaws in your database structure? What type of data are we talking about (passed via $_POST)?

Comment: Why you would like to store all posted data in a db?

Comment: i hope there is a form doing the posting somewhere?

Comment: What is the actual _purpose_ of “recording” all the posted data? If you just want this as a kind of log so that you can reconstruct later on what a user was posting should it turn out to be malicious or unwanted, then I’d say storing it as JSON or serialized into a single column is totally OK; whereas if you want to process that data in general at some point, maybe even _search_ in it for certain parameter names/values, then you might be better off with storing it as single parameter_name|value records, all tied together by an id for each single POST request made.

Comment: I agree with CBroe. It's "dead data" - never used again.

Comment: @CBroe basically the purpose is that if some user were to try and send cheesy stuff it would be all available to view and analyze. And what I've come to think of as a secondary use would be a user activity log where any user can view stuff they have posted, such as comments, threads and stuff like that. The only thing stopping me from using a normalized data structure ( second way ) is that I'm afraid it will get too big and slow in a matter of months. On the other hand having json data is really hard to handle with SQL, guess my only option is to use LIKE and hope for the best.. `:(`

Comment: So if the main purpose is not actually working with that data constantly, but only to “analyze” it when necessary, I’d go with serialized data. Easy enough to select it from the database by time of posting or by user id – and then the de-serializing part could be done by a script. And your secondary use, showing to the user what kind of content they have created – well that you should be able to get from the tables that actually hold that content.

Comment: @CBroe `you should be able to get from the tables that actually hold that content` I haven't thought of that, but maybe that's because it would be too hard, I have to join tables and execute complex queries where as in my current case I just retrieve records from a single table and `switch()` the type of content. Guess I'll go with serializing although it may not be considered correct. Thank you for your advice. I encourage you to post your last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what the actual purpose of “recording” all the posted data is. If you just want this as a kind of log so that you can reconstruct later on what a user was posting should it turn out to be malicious or unwanted, then I’d say storing it as JSON or serialized into a single column is totally OK; whereas if you want to process that data in general at some point, maybe even search in it for certain parameter names/values, then you might be better off with storing it as single parameter_name|value records, all tied together by an id for each single POST request made.

So if the main purpose is not actually working with that data constantly, but only to “analyze” it when necessary, I’d go with serialized data. Easy enough to select it from the database by time of posting or by user id – and then the de-serializing part could be done by a script. And your secondary use, showing to the user what kind of content they have created – well that you should be able to get from the tables that actually hold that content.